# Central Limit Theorem of a Ratio of Samples from $2$ Populations

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

I was hoping somebody could help me confirm if the following is true.

I have a stochastic process that I simulate in $2$ different modes: without optimizing and with optimizing. If the output of each mode has a reward that is iid, I can apply the central limit theorem to the mean reward for each mode.

My question is, if I take the ratio of the optimized rewards and the non-optimized rewards, can I still apply the central limit theorem to this ratio? To further clarify why I am doing this, I have $100$ samples from each population. Sample $1$ from the optimized population was simulated with the same random seed as sample 1 from the non-optimized population, and so forth. Thus, I want to know how good the optimization is relative to the non-optimized system on a sample basis, which is why I take the ratio of the samples from the optimized population and the samples from the non-optimized population.

As an example, say my samples are:

Population $A$ = Non-Optimized System

Population $B$ = Optimized System

Table of rewards:

| Random Seed | Reward in $A$ | Reward in $B$ | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $10$ | $15$ | $1.5$ |
| $2$ | $15$ | $30$ | $2.0$ |

...etc

I know I can apply CLT to the second and third columns, but can I apply it to the last one?

Comment: It's not clear what you're describing. What does optimization mean here? Anyway, CLT will hold as long as you have i.i.d. random variables (modulo regularity conditions).

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. What I mean is if I have samples from two populations that are i.i.d. random variables, can I apply the CLT to the ratio of the samples?

I have a stochastic process that I can run without any external interference (non-optimized system) or I can run it with external interference (optimized system). When I perform a simulation I ensure that the random seeds are the same for both cases and I want to confidence intervals for the improvement I can obtain with optimization relative to the non-optimized system.

Comment: Suppose you have $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ and $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ where each sequence is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. If, in addition, the two sequences are independent en masse, then $X_1/Y_1,X_2/Y_2,\ldots$ is also a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, and CLT holds (assuming the ratios are all well-defined and the variance is finite). Now, I don't know what numerical algorithm you use, but likely there is a deterministic relationship between $X_i$ and $Y_i$ if you use a common seed. Why don't you use different seeds?

Comment: If you want to run a diagnostic, probably you should plot the histogram of the errors first and take it from there?

Comment: Thanks. I use the same seed because each seed represents a scenario (same realization of uncertainties in the stochastic process). I want to compare the optimized system with the unoptimized system for each scenario, which is why I take the ratio. Ultimately, I want to say that on a scenario by scenario basis, optimization yields a certain % improvement, and provide confidence intervals for this

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. If we denote the seed by $\omega$, Reward in A by $f(\omega)$, and Reward in B by $g(\omega)$, then $f(\omega)/g(\omega)$ is i.i.d., so CLT holds. In any case, if what you want is a confidence interval, I don't see why you need CLT. Just get a lot of Ratios, and look at the 5th and 95th percentiles.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!